# Not able to identify the subview of TableView in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tags

I added a header view with a button & a imageview but I can not Identify the Imageview for changed the Image.

My code is as follow:

**My HaderView class .h file** (HeaderSection.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HeaderViewSection : UIView
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *btn;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *arrow_img;
@end
```

**My HaderView class .m file** (HeaderSection.m)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

        _arrow_img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        _arrow_img.frame=CGRectMake(280, 15, 20, 20);
        _arrow_img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow_down_section.png"];
        _arrow_img.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:_arrow_img];

        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 15, 35, 25);
        [btn setTitle:@"R" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:btn];

    }

    return self;
}
```

**.h file**

```
#import "HeaderViewSection.h"
@property (nonatomic,retain)HeaderViewSection *header_view;
```

**.m file**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    _header_view = [[HeaderViewSection alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    _header_view.tag = section+5000;
    _header_view.btn.tag = section+5000;
    [_header_view.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(expandTableHeaderView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _header_view.arrow_img.tag=section+2000;

    return _header_view;

}

-(void)expandTableHeaderView:(id)sender{

    [self.tblView beginUpdates];
    NSInteger section = [sender tag];
     UIView *view = (UIView *)[_header_view viewWithTag:[sender tag]]; //RETURNS nil
        NSArray *arr = [view subviews]; //RETURNS nil

}
```

**I don't know why this happen? Please Help me to solve this.**

Comment: @DivineDesert, what you want?

Comment: Ok, I understood your issue, did @C_X answer solved your issue ?

Comment: @DivineDesert, no not solved & just see my updated question.

Comment: what you get in [sender tag]

Comment: -(void)expandTableHeaderView:(id)sender{}
this medhod will be called only when button will be taped. So why you can have headerView simply by calling [sender superView]; and can change size of that headerView

Answer (score 0):

In this method you are creating new headerView. Now at this time there is no subView in headerView.
You are setting headerView.btn.tag but you did not add button in headerView, same is the case with image.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    _header_view = [[HeaderViewSection alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    _header_view.tag = section+5000;
UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc] init];//set frame also
button.tag = section+5000;
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(expandTableHeaderView:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[header_view addSubView:button];

   //Do same like image view

}
```

Edied:
As `-(void)expandTableHeaderView:(id)sender{ }` method will call only when you tap on button. Button is a subView of headerView. You can have header view by calling its `superView` method like this

```
UIView *view = (UIView*)[sender superView];
view.frame = // new frame
```

now view is you headerView, you can change its frame to expand or what ever you want.
You can get its subViews like this

```
NSArray *array = [view subViews];
for(UIView *v in array){
if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){
//v is imageview change image if you want
}
```

Comment: See my updated question because I already added the btn & imageview in a sepearate header class file

Comment: _header_view.tag = section+5000;
_header_view.btn.tag = section+5000;
you are setting same tag for the both view and button which can cause conflict. Change set different tag for the headerView.tag and btn.tag